# Which part of the C++ standard covers calling a method via a null pointer?

Tags: c++, standards

There are many questions on Stack Overflow that explain that the following is undefined behavior in C++:

```
MyType* p = nullptr;
p->DoSomething();
```

but I can't find one that cites the C++ standard. Which part of the C++11 and/or C++14 standards say that this is undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++14 [expr.ref]/2:

> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`

C++14 [expr.unary.op]/1:

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to **the object** or function **to which the expression points**.

The pointer does not point to an object, therefore this quote does not define the behaviour of `*p`. Nowhere else in the standard defines it either, so it is undefined behaviour.

Regarding whether a null pointer can be said to point to an object, N4618 [basic.compound]/3 defines pointer values as:

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object, or
> - the null pointer value for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.

which indicates that the null pointer value does not point to an object.

Comment: Thanks. Although it's a reasonable assumption, is there some language that says a null pointer doesn't point at an object? I'm also surprised this isn't explicitly called out as undefined, which is typical in the standard.

Comment: @jacobsa The text "A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory (1.7) or a null pointer (4.10). " suggests that the null pointer value is not the address of a byte in memory (therefore it cannot be the address of an object)

Comment: Nice find; will add that to the answer.

Comment: And talking about references, at 8.3.2.5 "... the only way
to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior."

Comment: Isn't the quote talking about the types of expression to which the operator can be applied, rather than its set of allowed values? A "pointer to an object type" isn't a pointer that points to a valid object.

Comment: @juanchopanza "lvalue referring to *the object* [...] to which the expression points"

Comment: Maybe you could emphasise that part? The preceding phrase kind of masks it.

Comment: I've submitted an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15404595) that adds the text from [basic.compound]/3, which is even clearer about null not being a pointer to an object in the latest [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound).